# Crystal Report Shows only first page

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I am using ASP.NET , SQL , Crystal Report. I have successfully generated Single page Reports. But when the report size exceed to more than one page, then Crystal Report only shows first page Data. When i click next button it shows "Source empty or No source found" like messages.

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rptDoc As New ReportDocument
    Dim ds As New StudentDataSet
    Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.TableName = "Crystal Report Example"
    sqlCon = New SqlConnection(myCon)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblStudent", sqlCon)
    da.Fill(dt)
    ds.Tables(0).Merge(dt)
    rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~\Reports\StudentList.rpt"))
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc

  End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You see, for most people, this doesn't happen. And you have not yet posted any details that set your case apart from most people, which means that there is no information in your question that people can use to answer it. Post source code, or other details so that people here have something to go by.

Comment: Well the exact message Box is "No valid report source is available". i can't post the image yet. It shows , when i click on Next Page button of crystal report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **code that loads the report must be execute on every postback**.
**Page_Init** is the right place where you can put this code (Page_Load can cause some errors).

Try this change (sorry for VB errors, i use C#):

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 ButtonClicked = true
 ShowReport()

Protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 ShowReport()

Protected Sub ShowReport() 
 Dim rptDoc As New ReportDocument
 Dim ds As New StudentDataSet
 Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection
 Dim dt As New DataTable
 dt.TableName = "Crystal Report Example"
 sqlCon = New SqlConnection(myCon)
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblStudent", sqlCon)
 da.Fill(dt)
 ds.Tables(0).Merge(dt)
 rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~\Reports\StudentList.rpt"))
 rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc

End Sub
```

Hey, it's reccomended to close ReportDocument on every page unload; this avoid an uncontrolled increase on a Report Counter that will stop the application

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (reportDocument != null)
        reportDocument.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but now it shows report on loading , without button Click. also , please explain what is ButtonClicked = true for. like you i am a VB Developer Only

Comment: Worked: instead of placing the ShowReport() in Page_Init, I have placed it in Page_Load with                                         If Page.IsPostBack Then
   Report()
 End If

Comment: I used a boolean variable called ButtonClicked that is set on button click, to avoid this problem

Comment: You can also dispose, after closing the report.